# Restrit access to some table record by user in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I need a generic way to restrict the access to some table records on an SQL Server instance by user.

The user should not be allowed to see any record that he is not allowed or any record that has a foreign key field that he is not allowed to see also (recursively).

There is any "Sql Server way" of doing this instead of making a "gazillion" inner joins with a permission table?

Comment: Permission table?why ? why don't you just `Deny` the permission

Comment: Do You want to permit only certain rows in table ?

Comment: Do you mean "Granting Row-Level Permissions in SQL Server"?

Comment: No. The foreign key relationships are there for data integrity ONLY. They were never designed to be a security mechanism.

Comment: @Whencesoever Yes and only if the record dont have any foreign key that the user dont have access also.

Comment: @António Try to read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669076(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The best option would be to restrict the user to a view that filters the results of your table properly.

Comment: Normally I avoid upvoting questions that don't answer the OP's question, however your answer does address the OP's problem and that, at the end of the day, is more relevant in this case. Hence the UV